# Time Stories Asylum: Missing card 59

Tags: time-stories

We are currently playing above game and card no. 59 is missing. Could anyone please post the text on the back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The question](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2259323/asylum-missing-card-59) is also asked on boardgamegeek. The back of the card looks like:

[image]

The text is: "You approach her, the young lady becomes totally absorbed by her strange painting and pays no attention to you."